# Running PCL in Hydro

Tags: pcl, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

It took me a while to run the sample code for down-sampling a point cloud using voxel grid, as given in tutorial page at : http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Tutorials?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=example_voxelgrid.cpp, tutorial link : http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Tutorials
I am using ROS Hydro on Ubuntu12.04, and catkin build. I am thinking of updating these links and add code for Hydro. Kindly let me know if some changes I made are redundent etc. Specifically I made the following changes:-

1. Code :

   - Deleted : #include <pcl/ros/conversions.h>
     Added: #include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
       #include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
   - Modified the callback function to use pcl::PCLPointCloud2 instead of sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 as:-
     (It's given at hydro migration : http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration)


     `void
     cloud_cb (const pcl::PCLPointCloud2ConstPtr& input)
     {
     pcl::PCLPointCloud2 cloud_filtered;
     pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PCLPointCloud2> sor;
     sor.setInputCloud (input);
     sor.setLeafSize (0.01, 0.01, 0.01);
     sor.filter (cloud_filtered);
     // Publish the dataSize
     pub.publish (cloud_filtered);
     }`
2. IN package.xml (from http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration 
   (....pcl is no longer packaged by the ROS community as a catkin package, so any packages which directly depend on pcl should instead use the new rosdep rules libpcl-all and libpcl-all-dev...... )
    and understood it (I think) by seeing the post at http://www.pcl-users.org/How-do-I-use-PCL-from-ROS-Hydro-td4029613.html (3rd comment : given by, Matteo Munaro Sep 12, 2013; 3:46pm), and also https://github.com/ros-perception/pcl_conversions/commit/a868e1a16e442c135f66a9738619d290bc4ee896) 
   Removed:  build_depend>pcl</build_depend>
          <run_depend>pcl</run_depend>
   Added:   <build_depend>libpcl-all-dev</build_depend>
           <run_depend>libpcl-all</run_depend>
   I am wondering if the addition of libpcl-all-dev and libpcl-all, could automatically be done while creting the package.
3. In CMakeList.txt 
   Removed: pcl dependency
   Added:   pcl_conversions dependency
   Again seeing the above mentioned link. Note: This could also be achieved by changing the package creation line to : catkin_create_pkg my_pcl_tutorial pcl_conversions pcl_ros roscpp sensor_msgs

I am quite sure that these changes must be done by many ppl who have run this tutorial and quite sad that they were not updated. Changes are a bit trivial once you understand, but still tutoral should run without giving any error, so that ppl like me could understand things easily :-).
Also is there a way to get libpcl-all-dev and libpcl-all directly in package.xml while creating the package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/90176/running-pcl-in-hydro/) by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2013-10-12

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have updated the tutorial, kindly let me know if it is correct.

---

The zip for my project it at: http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Tutorials?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=my_pcl_tutorial2.tar.gz

---

Originally posted by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) with karma: 339 on 2013-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mortonjt](https://answers.ros.org/users/4408/mortonjt/) on 2014-01-10**:
Thank you very much for posting your solution.  Do you mind if you could post your CMakelists.txt?  I'm still getting linker errors even with the changes that you suggested.

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2014-01-26**:
Hi, Sorry for the late reply, its running fine for me. I tried for pcl::PCLPointCloud2, and not pcl/PointCloud. I am uploading the zip file of my pcl project (named it 2 (my_pcl_tutorial2) as previous one was already there, which I have to move as example.cpp was in both). Link updated in answer.

**Comment by [lfelipesv](https://answers.ros.org/users/10721/lfelipesv/) on 2014-01-26**:
Hello aknirala, i followed your tutorial and is working for me. But now, I can't save one input Point Cloud 2 to a PCD File. I think I need to follow some conversions first. My code is here: http://answers.ros.org/question/121856/write-pcd-file-from-a-topic-hydro-pcl-migration/ Thank you!